# Rhino Mock Test Expected #1, Actual #0 - error

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks, rhino, expected-exception

I'm newbie working with Rhino Mock and I'm getting this error that I cannot understand why. Here the test

```
public void TestGet()
{
    var installationReference = new Guid("21D7D135-6E9E-4F92-8313-873CA3ABDCD8");
    var study = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IStudy>();
    var installation = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IInstallation>();
    var license = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ILicense>();
    var participant = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IStudyParticipant>();
    var clinicalPartner = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IClinicalPartner>();

    clinicalPartner.Stub(c => c.FirstName).Return("John");
    clinicalPartner.Stub(c => c.LastName).Return("Doe");
    installation.Stub(i => i.Reference).Return(installationReference);
    license.Stub(l => l.Installations).Return(new List<IInstallation> { installation });
    participant.Stub(p => p.Licenses).Return(new List<ILicense> { license });
    participant.Stub(p => p.ClinicalPartner).Return(clinicalPartner);
    participant.Stub(p => p.ClinicalPartnerStatus).Return(ClinicalPartnerStatus.Active);

    study.Stub(s => s.Description).Return("Test WebAPI");
    study.Stub(s => s.Participants).Return(new List<IStudyParticipant> { participant });

    repository.Stub(r => r.Query(Arg<GetStudiesByInstallationReference>.Matches(s => s.InstallationReference.Equals(installationReference))))
        .Return(new DummyResult<IStudy>(study));
    repository.Expect(r => r.Query(Arg<GetStudiesByInstallationReference>.Matches(s => s.InstallationReference.Equals(installationReference)))).Return(new DummyResult<IStudy>(study)).Repeat.Once();
    repository.VerifyAllExpectations();
}
```

My `GetStudiesByInstallationReference.cs`

```
public class GetStudiesByInstallationReference : IQuery<IStudy>
{
    public Guid InstallationReference { get; set; }

    public GetStudiesByInstallationReference(Guid installationReference)
    {
        InstallationReference = installationReference;
    }

    public IQueryResult<IStudy> Execute(ISession session)
    {
        var criteria = session.CreateCriteria<IStudy>();
        criteria.CreateAlias("participants", "p");
        criteria.CreateAlias("p.licenses", "l");
        criteria.CreateAlias("l.installations", "i");
        criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("i.Reference", InstallationReference));
        criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Status", StudyStatus.Approved));
        criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("p.ClinicalPartnerStatus", ClinicalPartnerStatus.Active));
        criteria.Add(Restrictions.Le("StartDate", DateTime.Now));
        criteria.Add(Restrictions.Or(
            Restrictions.IsNull("EndDate"),
            Restrictions.Gt("EndDate", DateTime.Now)));

        return new CriteriaResult<IStudy>(criteria);
    }
}
```

I want to test `GetStudiesByInstallationReference` was called one time.

What am I doing wrong?...it should pass the test as the `Expect` clause is the same used in the `Stub` but I still got the exception

> Expected #1, Actual #0.

Anybody could help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code sample doesn't include the type of `repository`, so it's not clear what that object is.  Note that you can only set expectations (ie: use `Expect()` or `Stub()`) on Interfaces or `virtual`/`abstract` members of concrete classes.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to test GetStudiesByInstallationReference was called one time.

`GetStudiesByInstallationReference` is a type, and not a method that you expect to be called.

```
repository
    .Expect(r => r.Query(Arg<GetStudiesByInstallationReference>.Matches(s => s.InstallationReference.Equals(installationReference))))
    .Return(new DummyResult<IStudy>(study)).Repeat.Once();
```

This line from your code is setting up an expectation on the `repository` mock. It expects that the `Query()` method is called with a parameter of type `GetStudiesByInstallationReference` that has the correct installation reference GUID as a property. If this method isn't called with the correct parameter, you will get the error you describe when calling `repository.VerifyAllExpectations()`.

It looks like your test is missing the actual call to the [SUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_under_test) i.e. the "Act" in [Arrange/Act/Assert](https://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/Oss/rhino-mocks/learn/Usage/assert-that-a-method-is-called-with-a-value-in-expected-state). Simply put, you need to execute some code that will cause the method on your repository to be called as you expect (or change the test).

Comment: Thanks for answering it. I'll check what you said with a colleague (whom wasn't here when I was creating this test)...he's used to use Rhino and probably will help me with it. The funny thing is, when I change the order of `Expect` (before the `Stub`) ...it works. I don't know if it's makes sense...